# How to do use a different theme on search result page instead of default?

Tags: theme, template, catalogsearch, custom-template

How do I make the search results page use a different theme like you can on category pages?

As, I'm using a different theme for a catalog on my store, but when you use the mini search it pulls the default store theme.

For example,

[image: Design Section of catalog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **You can assign custom theme using Event/Observer for Search result
> page**

Create **events.xml** at *`app/code/{VendorName}/{Modulename}/etc/frontend/`* and call an observer on `layout_load_before` event.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="ForcetoChangeTheme" 
            instance="{VendorName}\{Modulename}\Observer\ChangeTheme" />
    </event>
</config>
```

On the observer `ChangeTheme.php` at `{VendorName}\{Modulename}\Observer` change the theme programmatically.

```
<?php
namespace Devamitbera\ChangethemeAtCheckout\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ChangeTheme implements ObserverInterface
{
     /**
     * Design package instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface
     */
    private $_design;
    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $_storeManager;
    private $request;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface $design,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,   
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_design = $design;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        //$this->logger->info($this->request->getFullActionName());
        if($this->request->getFullActionName() =='catalogsearch_result_index'){
            $this->_design->setDesignTheme(1); //  1 is Theme id
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Works like a dream! Thank you so much for the help.